# SQL Server capitalize every first letter of every word with loop

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having difficulties trying to capitalize the first letter of every word. Since each field has more than 1 word, I am thinking I may need to create a loop or something similar to repeat the format in all words.

Here is my SELECT:

```
SELECT  UPPER(SUBSTRING(firstname,1,1))
    +   LOWER(SUBSTRING(firstname,2,LEN(firstname)))    + ' ' +
        UPPER(SUBSTRING(lastname,1,1))
    +   LOWER(SUBSTRING(lastname,2,LEN(lastname)))  +
        RTRIM(UPPER(SUBSTRING(position,1,1))
    +   LOWER(SUBSTRING(position,2,LEN(position))))         AS  information
```

Note that `firstname` comes from one column, `lastname` from another and `position` from another. The issue here is not `firstname` and `lastname`, which should be only a word for each column, but in the `position` column we should except such things as Software Developer or Business Analyst for example and I am not sure how to convert Software developer into Software Developer.

Comment: try using LEFT instead of using only substring: `UPPER(LEFT(firstname,1))+LOWER(SUBSTRING(firstname,2,LEN(firstname)))`

Comment: You're going to need a function since you don't know how many words will always be in the position column--but this is usually best handled in the application layer

Comment: See https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/139382/capitalize-only-the-first-letter-of-each-word-of-each-sentence-in-sql-server

Comment: I have seen other questions here but none of them apply exactly to what I am trying to accomplish. As you can see I know how to capitalize a word, what I need is to create a function or loop to capitalize several words.

Comment: Interesting approach @PM77-1. And Hendrix what are you trying to accomplish? You said capitlize every word... every suggestion thus far does that.